# Как сделать перемещение столбцов у таблицы?

Tags: vue.js

Что я хочу сделать, это перенести столбцы в таблице, допустим как в `exel` это реализовано. Если взять весь столбец и переместить его допусти из `B` в `A`, то весь столбец перенесется вместе с данными. Немного непонятно, как делается это во `vue`, да и логика непонятна: как должно это выглядеть, так чтобы перенеслось и состояние столбцов сохранилось.

Моя песочница без самой реализации *https://codesandbox.io/s/pyvjxxnnvj*
в файле `App.vue:27` если добавить атрибут `draggable` из библиотеки *https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable*, то я могу только `header` столбца переносить, а не весь столбец.

Пример:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll" @click="select"></th>
        <draggable>
          <th v-for="column in columns" @click="sortBy(column.name)">{{ column.label }}</th>
        </draggable>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

То я получу вот такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Типа такого надо *https://akottr.github.io/dragtable/*, только на vue.

Comment: хотел ответить на вопрос, начал пытаться, и понял, что тоже не въеду как решить =D

Comment: А зачем вам вообще vue.js? Сделайте черех jquery и все будет ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [пример](https://idushii.github.io/vue-component-table-columns-sort/index.html) реализации.

При разработке использовался обычный тег table, а для перемещения колонок методы mousedown, mouseover, mouseup.

Для начала перемещения используется событие mousedown (момент, когда кнопка мыши нажата, 
 но еще не отпущена).
При событии mouseover происходит обмен соседними колонками ( момент наведения мыши на другую колонку )

При событии mouseup происходит завершение обмена.

Для анимации перемещения (обмена) взят [пример](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) из документации vue js.

Так как данные таблицы передается в компонент через свойства (props), то при завершении обмена вызывается $emit `sort` с новым порядком колонок.

Соответственно, в родителе происходит обновление порядка колонок по событию `sort`.

Код:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'TableSortable',
  props: {
    rows:    { type: Array, default: () => ([]) },
    columns: { type: Array, default: () => ([]) },
  },
  data: () => ({
    isDraggbleColumn: null
  }),
  created() {
    document.onmouseup = this.ClearDraggble
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.ClearDraggble)
  },
  methods: {
    sort(column2) {
      if (!this.isDraggbleColumn || column2 == this.isDraggbleColumn) return;
      let columns = [...this.columns]
      let indexColumn1 = columns.findIndex( column => column == this.isDraggbleColumn )
      columns.splice(indexColumn1, 1)
      let indexColumn2 = columns.findIndex( column => column == column2 )
      let append = (indexColumn1 == indexColumn2) ? 1 : 0;
      columns.splice(indexColumn2 + append, 0, this.isDraggbleColumn)
      this.$emit('sort', columns)
    },
    ClearDraggble() {
      this.isDraggbleColumn = null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Удачного программирования.

Comment: Я задам вопрос. А зачем 2 template нужно. Один основной, а второй в tbody?

Comment: Второй template нужен для того упрощения понимания кода, это по сути просто обертка для остальных тегов. Линк https://github.com/idushii/vue-component-table-columns-sort/blob/master/src/components/TableSortable.vue

Comment: Спасибо большое